# Laravel fetching JSON column MariaDB syntax error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mysql-json

Im trying to fetch some datas depending on the JSON column `meta`. However, something weirds happen around the `->` symbol.

```
File::whereJsonContains('meta->serie', 'value')->toSql();
```

output

```
"select * from `files` where json_contains(`meta`->'$.\"serie\"', ?)"
```

Here is the error I get

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."serie"', ?)' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `files` where json_contains(`meta`->'$."serie"', "check_up"))

Schema

```
class File extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['filename', 'mime-type', 'path', 'meta', 'type'];

    protected $casts = [
        'meta' => 'array'
    ];

    const PATH = 'files';

    public function uploadable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function receivable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class FilesController extends Controller {

    public function download(Request $request) {
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'type' => 'required|alpha_dash',
            'meta' => 'sometimes|required',
        ]);

        $search = [
            ['type', $data['type']],
        ];

        if ($request->has('meta')) {
            foreach (json_decode($data['meta']) as $key => $value) {
                $search[] = ["meta->$key", 'like', $value];
            }
        }

        $files = File::where($search)->get();

        return response()->json($files);
    }
}
```

I tried using a regular `where` but it throws the same error. Any idea?

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you running?

Comment: `Server version: 10.3.7-MariaDB Homebrew` @Devon

Comment: Can you post your table schema and where statement you trying to implement

Comment: edited to include those @SevaKalashnikov

Comment: I think it's related to this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24542) MariaDB doesn't handle JSON queries the same way Mysql does

Comment: See also https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/811.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = $request->all();

$query = File::where('type', $data['type']);

if ($request->has('meta')) {
    foreach (json_decode($data['meta']) as $key => $value) {
        $query->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(meta, '\"{$value}\"', '$.{$key}')");    
    }
}

$files = $query->get();
```

Comment: i think that's the way to go but for some reasons, the rows im querying are not found. However when I remove the `json_contains` part, I can retreive them easily

Comment: Its the details I guess.. you need to troubleshoot the data you receive and compare it agains json stored.. well at least I got you heading in the right direction right?

Comment: yes. here's how the data is stored in the meta column
`"{\"angle\":\"lower\",\"serie\":\"check_up\"}"`
how would you query that?

Comment: Maybe try `$query->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(REPLACE(meta, '\\', ''), '{$value}', '{$key}')";` but its such a workaround for your case, might work but not sure if its a good approach

Comment: Finally, you got me in the right direction. I wasnt inserting the data correctly. I use json_encode when I didnt need to do it. Thanks

Comment: btw you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of `$query->` line

Comment: Yes I noticed that some time ago and made an edit but you must've still used unedited code xD